# addClass if specific class is not present on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am quite new to JS and have searched for an existing solution to this for some time now,. I am perhaps lacking in the terminology needed to yield such a specific solution. I am trying to create a series of four elements with active states, only one of which can be active at a time, and which open up a caption below when clicked. I am using a combination of `.addClass`, `.removeClass` and `.toggleClass` to achieve this.

[The result can be seen here.](http://wpf.matmartin.co.uk/) The html is long, but I can post it here if required.

I am almost there with this, but I cannot get the caption area to close again once it has opened up. Captions are absolutely positioned within a relative parent, so cannot affect the height of the parent themselves. I am using removeClass `.lcs-closed` from the element `#landercaptions` to open this space up when an element is active, but cannot find a way to make this revert when no elements are active.

I am thinking of this as follows: "if no element has the class `.sh-active`, add the class `.lcs-closed` to the `#landercaptions` element. I have tried various uses of `.hasClass` but not found anything that works after the page has loaded.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#one').click( function() {
            $("#capone").toggleClass("lc-hidden");  
            $("#captwo, #capthree, #capfour").addClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#two, #three, #four").removeClass('sh-active');
            $("#one").toggleClass('sh-active');
            $("#landercaptions").removeClass("lcs-closed");
        } );
        $('#two').click( function() {
            $("#captwo").toggleClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#capone, #capthree, #capfour").addClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#one, #three, #four").removeClass('sh-active');
            $("#two").toggleClass('sh-active');
            $("#landercaptions").removeClass("lcs-closed");
        } );
        $('#three').click( function() {
            $("#capthree").toggleClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#capone, #captwo, #capfour").addClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#one, #two, #four").removeClass('sh-active');
            $("#three").toggleClass('sh-active');
            $("#landercaptions").removeClass("lcs-closed");
        } );
        $('#four').click( function() {
            $("#capfour").toggleClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#capone, #captwo, #capthree").addClass("lc-hidden");
            $("#one, #two, #three").removeClass('sh-active');
            $("#four").toggleClass('sh-active');
            $("#landercaptions").removeClass("lcs-closed");
        } );
    </script>
```

How can I get this page to revert to the state it loads in when all elements are inactive (caption area closed)?

I am aware that the issue may be with the JS I am already using, and will welcome suggestions to change this if necessary.

**EDIT** as requested here is the html too:

```
<div class="landercols">    
<div class="lcheader">
    <h1 class="center">GoParenting. For growing families.</h1>
</div>
<div class="onefourth">
    <div class="stepholder" id="one"></div>
    <div class="steptitle">
        <h3 class="center">About</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="onefourth">
    <div class="stepholder" id="two"></div>
    <div class="steptitle">
        <h3 class="center">Asking</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="onefourth">
    <div class="stepholder" id="three"></div>
    <div class="steptitle">
        <h3 class="center">Action</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="onefourth">
    <div class="stepholder" id="four"></div>
    <div class="steptitle">
        <h3 class="center">And then...</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="landercaptions" class="lcs-closed">
    <div class="landercaption lc-hidden" id="capone">
        <h5 class="center narrow">At GoParenting we specialise in working with families with children aged two to eighteen, and have worked with hundreds of parents with an extremely varied range of parenting issues. We share positive parenting strategies with mums and dads to help them manage their children’s behaviour and improve their family relationships.</h5>
        <a href="http://wpf.matmartin.co.uk/about">
            <div class="button" id="midfloat">
                <h6>About GoParenting</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="landercaption lc-hidden" id="captwo">
        <h5 class="center narrow">Parenting can be tough, but asking for help doesn’t have to be. Bringing up children is one of the hardest jobs we do in our lives but we don’t receive any training for it - we have to learn as we go. When you ask GoParenting for support you are taking a huge step toward becoming a stronger, happier parent.</h5>
        <a href="http://wpf.matmartin.co.uk/contact">
            <div class="button" id="midfloat">
                <h6>Contact us</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="landercaption lc-hidden" id="capthree">
        <h5 class="center narrow">When you ask GoParenting for help we will discuss how you would like us to support you. We will then create a tailored plan for you to follow, which will include weekly emails and calls. We will also follow up after support ends to see how things are going.</h5>
        <a href="http://wpf.matmartin.co.uk/how-it-works">
            <div class="button" id="midfloat">
                <h6>How it works</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="landercaption lc-hidden" id="capfour">
        <h5 class="center narrow">The GoParenting strategies we discuss are tailored to your needs. They are confidential and designed to help you with whatever changes you would like to make right now. They will also be invaluable in helping you to support your children long into the future as they grow and develop.</h5>
        <a href="http://wpf.matmartin.co.uk/testimonials">
            <div class="button" id="midfloat">
                <h6>How we've helped other parents</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you do just `$(".sh-active")` it return an element. So `if (! $(".sh-active") ){} `is basicly if this class doesn't exists do something.

Comment: Giving that you are already using jQuery, you can use `hasClass("sh-active")` method

Comment: Use classes rather than IDs: `$('.sh').click(function() { $(".sh").removeClass("sh-active"); $(this).addClass("sh-active"); });`

Comment: @user5014677 thank you. i thought i had tried this but was not getting the result i needed. how would you implement this?

Comment: @Morpheus as with @user5014677's suggestion, this is something i have been trying to use for hours now. can you explain how you would use the `hasclass` method please?

Comment: Write you html and css and you will get an answer. With only js it's hard to give a complete answer, that's why everyone is giving you suggestions in comments.

Comment: thanks @user5014677. i wasn't sure if it was TMI. i've added it in above.

Comment: @mtm you need to include your generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: @user5014677 `!$(".sh-active")` - always evaluates to `false`

Comment: @mtm to see if there are elements on the page with a given class, you need to check how items are in the returned jQuery wrapper `if ($(".sh-active").length == 0) { ... }`.

Comment: @Igor Did yo u try it?

Comment: @hungerstar of course, and thanks. i'm new to foruming too.

Comment: @mtm hungerstar is correct. You need to give the full HTML on the page after rendering, not the PHP (since JavaScript interacts with the full HTML).

Comment: @user5014677 - see below

Comment: @Makaze yes, thanks. that's done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if there are elements on the page with a given class, you need to check how many items are in the returned jQuery wrapper

```
if ($(".sh-active").length == 0) { 
  //... 
}
```

For @user5014677: `!$(".sh-active")` - always evaluates to `false`.

```js
console.log($(".existing-class").length);
console.log(!$(".existing-class"));
console.log($(".non-existing-class").length);
console.log(!$(".non-existing-class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="existing-class"></div>
```

As the desire is to have resulting code in the accepted answer, I am including a fragment from @mtm's response here:

```
$('#one').click( function() {
    $("#capone").toggleClass("lc-hidden");  
    $("#captwo, #capthree, #capfour").addClass("lc-hidden");
    $("#two, #three, #four").removeClass('sh-active');
    $("#one").toggleClass('sh-active');
    $("#landercaptions").removeClass("lcs-closed");
    if ($(".sh-active").length == 0) { 
        $("#landercaptions").addClass("lcs-closed");
    }
} );
```

Comment: This will work, provided you put this condition around the last line of each `.click()` handler.

Comment: thanks @igor, but i'm afraid i don't fully understand. i did try using this method - `if ($(".sh-active").length == 0)` - but not with any success. is it the case that this is checked on load, but that further changes to the html after this won't create these conditional responses?

Comment: @Makaze that's encouraging - can you help out a learner and show me how you would compose this please?

Comment: i've been fiddling - i think i have it now but i'm not sure how to put it in a comment.

Comment: adding that wrapper around a negation of the last line of each `.click()` handler has done it. as follows: `if ($(".sh-active").length == 0) { $("#landercaptions").addClass("lcs-closed");}`